# Get user Id in instagram

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, instagram

I try to using instagram api within vs using [c#,windows form] and I try with calling the url to get the access token and no problem with this issue but I need to know how to get the user id number for the authenticated user !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

1. the oAuth URI will have a respnse type key with "code" as value.
2. then  with the returned code I perform a request with other parameters like client id and client secrets..etc
3. read the response which will return a json object with user Id

In details see [here](http://ashs3d.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/get-the-user-id-for-instagram-api/)

Answer (score 4):

In the world of HTTP Request, you can obtain everything :)
Send your request to this url to get user public info.

https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1

E.g:
https://www.instagram.com/therock/?__a=1

Comment: and how to parse result?

Comment: You can use JSON parser library for your specified language.
Example : 
- In Javascript you can using Json.parse built-in method.
- In C#/.NET you can use Json.NET library. ( Newtonsoft.Json )

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check what the API response is. I would use https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/. You can get the user id fast to verify its the same